# How to call UIViewController from cocos2d-x?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, cocos2d-x

How to call UIViewController from cocos2d-x?

I develop my app in cocos2d-x(C++). For iOS & Android, I have to write native code.(Objective-c,java).

I want to call UIViewController.The following code crash.

```
void NativeLauncher::CallMyViewController(){
    UIViewController *myViewController = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController;
    QRViewController *newViewController = [[MainViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"MainViewController" bundle:nil];
    [myViewController presentViewController: newViewController animated:YES completion: nil];//crash
}
```

Anyone know how to do?

Comment: See http://www.notthepainter.com/full-cocos2d-uikit-integration/

Answer (score 1):

Just use this code in your .mm class,this is the way to call any viewController from cocos2d-x

```
ViewController *newViewController = [[ViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
AppController *appController = (AppController *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    [appController.viewController presentViewController:newViewController animated:YES completion:Nil];
```